# manually writing .xml

Tags: android, xml

Hi I am developping and application in android and I haven't come accross any .xml guides for android.And since the code is auto-generated by the builder I though it would be ok.Nonetheless now I've reached  to a point that I need to put simple buttons on the bottom of the screen to an equal distance  from left and right but can't seem to make it work.I put the margins to be 19dp(one from the left and one from the right) but still doesn't work.So i know it is not a worth-while question but can you provide  me at least some articles i can read?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_btn_0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Absences"
        android:checked="true" 
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_small"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_btn_1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Students"
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_small" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_btn_2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Grades" 
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_small"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_btn_3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Tests" 
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_small"/>
</RadioGroup>
<com.github.ysamlan.horizontalpager.HorizontalPager
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1">        
    <DragNDrop.DragNDropListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </DragNDrop.DragNDropListView>        
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Students menu"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#0f0" />
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Grades menu"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#00f" />
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Tests"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#0f0" />
    </ScrollView>     
</com.github.ysamlan.horizontalpager.HorizontalPager>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/a19dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/r"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="Refresh"
    android:textSize="@dimen/a12" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/a19dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="Return"
    android:textSize="@dimen/a12" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where is your "what have you tried" section? Mind posting it.

Comment: I Agree with Andro Selva. But did you try a relative layout (standard it is linear)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="98dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Button" />
```

`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` means that the bottom must be on the bottom.
`android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` means it should be in the center (so even space on left and right)

for your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_btn_0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Absences"
        android:checked="true" 
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_small"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_btn_1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Students"
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_small" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_btn_2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Grades" 
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_small"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_btn_3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Tests" 
        android:textSize="@dimen/padding_small"/>
</RadioGroup>
<com.github.ysamlan.horizontalpager.HorizontalPager
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1">        
    <DragNDrop.DragNDropListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </DragNDrop.DragNDropListView>        
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Students menu"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#0f0" />
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Grades menu"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#00f" />
    </ScrollView>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:text="Tests"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#0f0" />
    </ScrollView>     
</com.github.ysamlan.horizontalpager.HorizontalPager>
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/r"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="Refresh"
    android:textSize="@dimen/a12" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:text="Return"
    android:textSize="@dimen/a12" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I changed  `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` instead of that 19dp thing. And made it a relativelayout

Comment: ok i used your code but now while it looks better it's not what i was aiming for.you see no i have a button on the bottom and the other one is on top of the first:/

Comment: @libathos I edited my answer, I misunderstood you the first time.

Comment: @libathos I can't use your layout into mine, because of serveral things (like `</com.github.ysamlan.horizontalpager.HorizontalPager>`) So I can't check it. But I just suggest you to "play" a little. 
 take the buttons away, see if list appears, then place 1 button and check again, and so on. (This is how I do things if I can't figure it out)